# Switch between IIS and Apache based on the requested URL?

Tags: apache-2.2, iis, url, forwarding

I have two webservers installed on one machine:

- Apache running on port `8080`
- IIS on port `80`

I want to define a rule in IIS that whenever someone wants to access my server in the form of `apache.myserver.org` the visitor should be redirected to `myserver.org:8080`. In any other cases the IIS on port `80` should be used as webserver.

Is that possible with the IIS?

Comment: It's certainly possible with Apache (without having to rely on an additional component)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a reverse proxy. This should be helpful:

http://blogs.iis.net/wonyoo/archive/2008/07/09/application-request-routing-arr-as-a-reverse-proxy.aspx

For pattern, you'll need to use `apache.myserver.org` or `*apache.myserver.org*` - not sure about that so you should experiment a bit.